# d3 - arrowhead not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart where in I need to point an arrow at a specific bar and giving it a short label. I was able to get the arrow line, but the arrow head is not showing up. 
What is that I am doing wrong? 
MY code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

line {
    stroke: black;
}

path.marker {
    fill: black;
}

path {
    stroke: black;
    fill: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2 style="text-align:center;">Head And Neck Therapy </h2>
            </div>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Data OverView</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div id=chartId style="margin-top:50px; margin-left:50px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cameronspear.com/downloads/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <style>
        .jumbotron {
                padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
                h1 {
                    font-size: 2em;
                }
                p {
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                    .btn {
                        padding: 0.5em;
                    }
                }
            }

        </style>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>" + d.letter + " constitute : </strong> <span style='color:red'> " + d3.format(".2f")(d.frequency) + "% out of total population size</span>";
  })


var svg = d3.select("#chartId").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {

var sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return +d.frequency;});
//this will convert teh frequency into percent
data.forEach(function(d){ d.frequency = (d.frequency/sum)*100});
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, 100]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

      svg.selectAll("text.label")
        .data(data.filter(function(d) { return d.frequency == ((441/sum)*100); }))
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()/2;
        }).attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.frequency) - 70;
        })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Your Patient");

        svg.selectAll("line.arrow")
            .data(data.filter(function(d) { return d.frequency == ((441/sum)*100); }))
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "arrow")
            .attr("x1", function (d) {
                return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()/2;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()/2;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return y(d.frequency) - 67;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return y(d.frequency) - 10;
            })
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  d.frequency = d3.format(".2f")(d.frequency)
  return d;
}



</script>
</html>
```

The data.tsv file is as follows:

```
letter  frequency
Asian   4
African-American    96
White   441
Hispanic    81
Other   11
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
.attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

There is no marker in the `svg defs` with Id `arrow`.

Refer:
http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/d59de83f771ca2b6f1d4
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker

Comment: According to the document, it says there's a marker defined arrow-head.. Will it work if I change it to arrowHead?

Comment: No in your code the defs is missing  you need to add that before you use it  as marker-end